# I am using Angular CLI + Angular 2 with spring boot. my application is running as expected with out having issue. but the issue is if i run ng test

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using Angular CLI + Angular 2 with spring boot. My application is running as expected without having an issue.

Butthe issue is, if I run `ng test` I am getting the following exception:

`Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events. Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info. 
Built project successfully.`

```
Stored in "dist". Build successful - 1128ms.
07 07 2016 17:25:14.398:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/  
07 07 2016 17:25:14.418:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at 
07 07 2016 17:25:14.423:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome 07 07 2016 17:25:16.514:
INFO [Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.5)]: Connected on socket /#0TaliUxVtqlcFROBAAAA with id 93440436 

Chrome 51.0.2704 (Mac OS X 10.11.5) AccountSummary Service should ... FAILED
Error: No provider for Http! (AccountSummaryService -> Http)
```

Error: DI Exception`

Comment: from the error `FAILED Error: No provider for Http! (AccountSummaryService -> Http)` 

  try `import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';


bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS] );`

in your main.ts

Comment: Can you accept as correct answer or if there is some point of question that I don't cover, let me now.

Answer (score 1):

Because, angular-CLI creates default account-summary-service.spec file that does not have an injection of Http module.

If you comment  out the following code:

```
  // beforeEachProviders(() => [AccountSummaryService]);
  //
  // it('should ...',
  //     inject([AccountSummaryService], (service: AccountSummaryService) => {
  //   expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  // }));
```

There will be no error.

OR

Inject Http service also in tests. A test for this service would look like this:

```
describe('AccountSummaryService Service', () => {

  let accountSummaryService: AccountSummaryService;
  let mockBackend: MockBackend;

  const mockHttpProvider = {
    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
    useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
      return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
  }

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    provide(Http, mockHttpProvider),
    AccountSummaryService
  ]);

  beforeEach(inject([AccountSummaryService, MockBackend], (a, m) => {
    accountSummaryService = a;
    mockBackend = m;
  }));

  it('should ...', async(() => {
      expect(accountSummaryService).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```